# finding all composition series of ${\rm sym} \ (4)$

Tags: finite-groups, permutations

How can I find all composition series of ${\rm sym}\ (4)$ ? I think first I have to find all maximal normal subgroups. But how ? Thanks.

Comment: In order to find all the *maximal* normal subgroups you should start off by listing all the normal subgroups : there aren't too many of them! Now just answer the question, which are maximal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without words:

$$1\lhd \{(1)\,,\,(12)(34)\}\lhd\{(1)\,,\,(12)(34)\,,\,(13)(24)\,,\,(14)(23)\}\lhd A_4\lhd     S_4$$

Comment: Ok. I can find all normal subgroups of $S_{4}$. But what about  $A_{4}$? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can check that directly. Just take into account that $\;A_4\;$ has no subgroup of order $\;6\;$ , and all the rest is pretty easy if you check the Sylow subgroups. Hint: $\;A_4\;$ has one single non-trivial *proper* normal subgroup.

Answer (score -2):

this isn't correct, since {(1),(12)(34)} is only a subgroup of A4, but isn't normal,
since a normal subgroup is a union of complete conjugacy classes, and elt (12)(34)
isn't a complete c.class.

or, try conjugation of {(1),(12)(34)} by elt (123) (which is even) and you get 
{(1),(14)(23)} not ={(1),(12)(34)}.

of course {(1),(12)(34)}⊲{(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)}
is true, since {(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)} is abelian, and every subgroup of
an abelian group is Normal, but {(1),(12)(34)} isn't normal in A4